# Multer in Nextjs, req.file is undefined

Tags: файлы, nextjs, multer

`pages/api/upload`:

```js
export default async (req: INextReq, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    if (req.method !== "GET") {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Use only GET method" });
    }

    return UploadLogics.testUpload(req)
        .then((data) => res.status(200).json(data))
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).json(error));
};
```

`UploadLogics`:

```js
class UploadLogics {
    static async testUpload(req: INextReq) {
        uploadService("file", "SINGLE", "user");
        return { file: `File: ${req.file}` };
    }
}
```

`uploadService`:

```js
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
};

export default (name: string, type: TType, directory: TDirectory) => {
    const allowedTypes: Array<string> = ["SINGLE", "ARRAY"];

    if (!allowedTypes.includes(type)) {
        throw new Error(`Type ${type} not support. See this types: ${allowedTypes.join(", ")}`);
    }

    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, path.relative(`${PROJECT_ROOT}`, `./public/uploads/${directory}`));
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
        }
    });

    const image = multer({ storage, limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 } });

    let upload = null;

    switch (type) {
        case SINGLE:
            upload = image.single(name);
            break;
        case ARRAY:
            upload = image.array(name);
            break;
        default:
            return upload;
    }

    return upload;
};
```

Возвращает undefined при выводе req.file, что может быть не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pages/api/upload:

```js
import { check, validationResult } from "express-validator";
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import UploadLogics from "../../server/logics/upload.logics";
import { INextReq } from "../../server/middlewares/authentication.middleware";
import initMiddleware from "../../server/middlewares/init.middleware";
import validateMiddleware from "../../server/middlewares/validate.middleware";
import nc from "next-connect";
import uploadService from "../../server/services/upload.service";

const validateBody = initMiddleware(validateMiddleware(
    [
        check("file", "Вы должны выбрать фото").notEmpty()
    ],
    validationResult
));

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
};

const handler = nc({
    onError: (err, req, res: NextApiResponse, next) => {
        console.error(err.stack);
        return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Something broke!" });
    }
})
    .use(uploadService("user").single("file"))
    .post(async (req: INextReq, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Use only POST method" });
        }

        await validateBody(req, res);

        return UploadLogics.testUpload(req)
            .then((data) => res.status(200).json(data))
            .catch((error) => res.status(400).json(error));
    });

export default handler;
```

upload logics:

```js
class UploadLogics {
    static async testUpload(req: INextReq) {
        return { file: `File: ${req.file.filename}` };
    }
}
```

upload service:

```js
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";

type TDirectory = "user" | "post";

export default (directory: TDirectory) => {
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, `public/uploads/${directory}`);
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
        }
    });

    const image = multer({ storage, limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 } });
    return image;
};
```